# Flattern LINQ Query SelectMany Result

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have seen similar questions, but none the same. I have some complex queries such as:

```
        var myResults = await context.Loot
            .Include(x => x.LootTable)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Notes)
            .SelectMany(t => t.LootTable, (reward, x) => reward.LootTable
                .SelectMany(y => y.Notes, (l, x) => new MyStuff(

                    reward.rewardId,
                    l.lId,
                    x.Date,
                    "Red",
                    reward.Type,
                    l.Title,
                    x.DisplayName,
                    "Weapon",
                    x.Message
                ))).ToListAsync();
```

I am trying to get a List of MyStuff objects, but the above gives me multiple Lists of MyStuff. How to I flatten it into one list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in "Flatten" operator, but you can do `.SelectMany(x => x)` to flatten the results:

```
var myResults = ...;
var flattenedResults = myResults.SelectMany(x => x);
```